# Cannot change ownership in SSHFS/FUSE

Tags: permissions, chown, sshfs, fuse, ownership

I encounter permission denied when trying to change the owner using `chown` of a folder on mounted SSHFS:

```
# /etc/fstab
sshfs#ubuntu@my.remote.tld:/mnt/data  /data   fuse    user,_netdev,nonempty,reconnect,allow_other,idmap=user,delay_connect,workaround=all  0   0
```

Then both when running as `ubuntu` and `root`:

```
$ chown other:other /data/test
chown: changing ownership of '/data/test': Permission denied
$ ll /data
total 24K
drwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu  16K Aug 20 16:01 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Aug 22 20:32 test
```

Any hint what should be configured differently please? I read and tried multiple SSHFS options but so far no good...

(`chmod` works fine)

Comment: Read https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs#about . Can you change ownership using SFTP? If not, you can't using sshfs. You could try having the sshfs using sftp as remote root user (and not ubuntu), which is the only remote user which could have a chance to do this.